# RStudio: How to cite bibtex reference with special symbol in cite-key

Tags: r, rstudio

I am writing a manuscript using RStudio's R Markdown. All references are saved in an external bib file that is referenced in the R Markdown document's YAML

```
---
title: "My Manuscript"
bibliography: "templates/export_2020-06-22.bib"
---
```

The bibtex entries are auto-populated by my reference manager. Sometimes the name is not compatible with RStudio citations. In the example below, the name for the entry is `10.1016/s0140-6736(95)90120-5`, but RStudio doesn't like the parentheses in the name. Is there a way cite this bib entry in RStudio?

```
@article{10.1016/s0140-6736(95)90120-5, 
author = {Rothwell, P M}, 
title = {{Can overall results of clinical trials be applied to all patients?}}, 
issn = {0140-6736}, 
doi = {10.1016/s0140-6736(95)90120-5}, 
pmid = {7783541}, 
abstract = {{It is generally assumed that...}}, 
pages = {1616--1619}, 
number = {8965}, 
volume = {345}, 
journal = {The Lancet}, 
year = {1995}
}
```

When I try to cite this entry with `[@10.1016/s0140-6736(95)90120-5]`, this is what I see in the knitted document:
[image]

Comment: While unsatisfying, I think the easiest solution would be to find a workaround to make your reference manager use simpler cite keys :/ Zotero for examples lets you use AuthorYearShortTitle, which should be unproblematic for RMarkdown/pandoc

Comment: what happens if you put it between ` (those marks before your 1 on the keyboard)? That is usually my way around when a entry/name/variable isn't compatible with R.

Comment: I join what was said ... it is always better to "clean" things upstream (ideally at the source). I do not know which refmanager you use, but check out the options ... or use an alternative refmanager like Zotero or JabRef ... if you cannot convince your reference manager to "use" nicer ref keys or cannot move to another refmanager, bib files are "textfiles" and you could read the bib file and substitute the parantheses with a hyphen (as these are apparently understood correctly by RMarkdown/pandoc).

Comment: Thank you for the comments....I was hoping to keep the citekey what it was (defaults to the DOI). But this DOI is not playing nicely with the others.  I was hoping it could be handled in RStudio, but if not, will update in the ref manager.